# How to create image gallery with animation

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I need to create image gallery with animation (effects), And add panel and hyperlink to each image.
such as http://www.microsoft.com/en-lk/default.aspx

How can do that?

Comment: You can easily find powerful open sourced php galleries on the web. Google for them then watch their demo and source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is too broad it can be done in so may different ways using different menthods etc..

Here are a few links to point you in the right direction:

http://wowslider.com (Perfect if your just starting out)

http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider

or if you want to try and build it yourself start with a tutorial such as this:

http://line25.com/tutorials/build-a-simple-image-slideshow-with-jquery-cycle